Convergents of continued fraction for quadratic implied by an inequality
Assume that $d$ is a positive squarefree integer and $p$ and $q$ are positive integers such that $$-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2} < p^2-dq^2 \leq \sqrt{d}.$$  I want to show that $p/q$ is a convergent in the continued fraction for $\sqrt{d}$.  I tried to show that $|\sqrt{d}-\tfrac{p}{q}|<\tfrac{1}{2q^2}$. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The case where $p^2 - n q^2 >0,$   so $0 < p^2 - n q^2 < \sqrt n $  Factor.. $ \frac{p}{q}  > \sqrt n $  so  $ \frac{p}{q} + \sqrt n >   2 \sqrt n $   and
$$ \frac{1}{  \frac{p}{q} + \sqrt n} < \frac{1}{2 \sqrt n}    $$
And
$$ \frac{p^2 - n q^2}{q^2} = \left( \frac{p}{q} + \sqrt n \right)  \left( \frac{p}{q} - \sqrt n \right)  < \frac{ \sqrt n}{q^2} $$
Multiply inequalities
$$    \left( \frac{p}{q} - \sqrt n \right)  < \frac{ 1}{2q^2} $$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Saturday morning.
The case where $p^2 - n q^2 < 0$    So far I have
$$ 0 <  \sqrt n -  \frac{p}{q} < \frac{\sqrt n - \frac{1}{2}}{2 p q}    $$
This is pretty good,  as it has already the $2$ in the denominator,  while $p \approx q \sqrt n.$  Things improve for large $q$
Maybe this will work out

I finally figure out what do do. The case $0<p^2-dq^2<\sqrt{d}$ was answered by Will Jagy. (Thank you!).  Assume now that $-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2}<p^2-dq^2<0$. Then $p>\sqrt{dq^2-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2}}$ and
\begin{gather*}
|p^2 - q d^2 | < \sqrt{d}-\tfrac{1}{2} \\
q\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{d}\right|(p+\sqrt{d}q) < \sqrt{d}-\tfrac{1}{2} \\
\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{d}\right| < \frac{\sqrt{d}-\tfrac{1}{2}}{q(p+\sqrt{d}q)} \\
\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{d}\right| < \frac{\sqrt{d}-\tfrac{1}{2}}{q(\sqrt{dq^2-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2}}+\sqrt{d}q)} \\
\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{d}\right| < \frac{\sqrt{d}-\tfrac{1}{2}}{q^2(\sqrt{d+(-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2})\tfrac{1}{q^2}}+\sqrt{d})} \\
\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt{d}\right|<\frac{1}{2q^2}.
\end{gather*}
The last inequality implies that $p/q$ is a convergent of $\sqrt{d}$.
The last step in the above calculation is true because
\begin{gather*}
2(\sqrt{d}-\tfrac{1}{2}) < \sqrt{d+(-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2})\tfrac{1}{q^2}}+\sqrt{d} \\
\Leftrightarrow \qquad (\sqrt{d}-1)^2 < d+ (-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2})\tfrac{1}{q^2} \\
\Leftrightarrow \qquad d-2\sqrt{d}+1 < d+ (-\sqrt{d}+\tfrac{1}{2})\tfrac{1}{q^2} \\
\Leftrightarrow \qquad (\tfrac{1}{q^2}-2)\sqrt{d}+1 < \frac{1}{2q^2}.
\end{gather*}
The last inequality is true when $d>1$ since the left-hand side is negative.
